# Why is an orthonormal basis ordered

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

In textbook an orthonormal basis is defined as an ordered basis that is orthonormal. Is there any specific reason why we define it as "ordered"?

Comment: Typically all bases are ordered, as that's necessary for a basis to determine, e.g., a unique matrix representation of a linear map with respect to the given basis.

Comment: @Travis Willse Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically *any* basis is by definition ordered, and that's necessary for practical computation with matrix representations: Given a basis $(E_a)$ of a vector space $\Bbb V$, the matrix representation of a vector $$v = \sum v^a E_a \in \Bbb V$$ is $$\pmatrix{v^1\\\vdots\\v^n} ,$$ so reordering the basis permutes the entries of the matrix representation, and in particular the matrix representation depends on the order.

If you've encountered orientations of vector spaces, you know that any (ordered) basis $\mathcal B$ determines an orientation by declaring $\mathcal B$ to be an oriented $n$-tuple. Permuting the basis elements preserves the orientation if the permutation is even but reverses it if the permutation is odd, so the determined orientation depends on order, too.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @TravisWillse with respect to order and orientation for any basis refers to a non canonical ordering. Orthogonality of the basis is a way to make it canonical as applied in a billinear or generally multilinear context.